# What do types mean in haskell

Tags: haskell, theory, function-declaration, type-declaration

I got asked this question in a class that left me pretty confused, we were presented with the following:

For the bellow type declarations:

```
ranPositions :: Image -> Dims -> [Point] 
getBlockSums :: Image -> Dims -> [Point] -> [BlockSum]
i :: Image
d :: Dims
```

What are the types of the following ? *isn't it the above?!*

```
ranPositions i d
getBlockSums i d
```

So what I responded was this:

```
type ranPositions = Array Point Int, (Int, Int)
type getBlockSums = Array Point Int, (Int, Int)

// Because (this was given)

type Image = Array Point Int 
type Dims = (Int, Int)
```

Apart from being wrong, this question confused me because i thought the type of a function was what was declared after the `::` and therefore it had been already given, no?

I could do with a bit of explaining and I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: check out [Currying](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Currying) in the HaskellWiki

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of `ranPosition i d` is `[Point]` - (currying gives you a function that returns `[Point]`)

The type of `getBlockSums i d` is `[Point] -> [BlockSum]` - (currying gives you a function that returns a function from `[Point]` to `[BlockSum]`)

Answer (score 3):

Sure, but they asked for the types of **expressions**, not **functions**.

Is it not obvious that the type of the following expressions:

```
foo 
foo a
foo a b
```

must all be different? If this is not clear to you, then go back and read about function application.

Comment: Technically, they don't _have_ to be different.  Compare the type of `id`, `id id`, `id id id`.  But in general, yes, they should be different.
A good example could be
(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int  -- Takes two numbers and adds them
(1+) :: Int -> Int        -- Takes one number and adds one to it
(1+2) :: Int              -- Takes zero numbers and returns 3

Comment: @Tyr - This is tricky, but one could argue that id :: forall a. a -> a is polymorphic, while the expression (id id) is not, it's a monomorphic function for some unknmown type. The difference can be seen in quite contrived examples like **case id id of f -> (f id, f const)** which should not typecheck, while **(id id, id const)** does. OTOH, **case id of f -> (f id, f const)** shouldn't type check either, so one is justified again in saying that id and id id is the same.

Comment: I was going by the output from :t in GHCi, and what it'd reduce to under evaluation.